# executable in URL

Tags: cgi

While I was planning a trip on a railroad website, I noticed the website was rendered by a .exe ( http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe )

My question: is this a CGI script, and if so, isn't that terribly inefficient?
I mean, every query launches a new thread.  Imagine a train gets cancelled, the server would be DDoS'd in no time, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put anything into a URL structure using [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting), so this could really mean anything. Maybe the planners of the portal preferred `.exe` to signify an action; maybe indeed an executable is called via CGI. Chances are it's a custom-built web server anyway.

You'd have to ask the people who built bahn.de's traffic information for a definitive reply - as far as I know, it's [these guys.](http://www.hacon.de/)